# EF Core Database Update Failed Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I'm attempting to add a table (StatusList)  to our database and configure the relationships for it between two other entities using entity framework. After creating the migration, when I update the database, I receive this error:

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (TheDatabase, CONSTRAINT 'FK_ProductType_StatusList_StatusListId' FOREIGN KEY ('StatusListId') REFERENCES 'StatusList' ('StatusListId') ON DELETE CASCADE)

The new entity (StatusList) and the two entities it's related to:

```
public class StatusList
{
    public int StatusListId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Status> Statuss { get; set; }
}


public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public int StatusListId { get; set; }
    public StatusList StatusList { get; set; }
}

 public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int StatusListId { get; set; }
    public StatusList StatusList { get; set; }
}
```

There is no other configuration for these entities.

I tested making the foreign key for StatusList on ProductType nullable, thinking this may be similar to the ["may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), but that didn't resolve it.

If we add entries to the StatusList table and then set the values for the foreign keys, we're then able to set the foreign key constraint using SQL.

I've previously added new entities to this database, and not had any issues adding the corresponding foreign keys. I'm not sure what is different about this scenario from past updates. How do I correctly handle this migration in EF Core so that the entity classes and migrations are correct?